# How to store and search per minute data effectively in mysql DB?

Tags: mysql, performance

I am trying to take records per minute for 200 powermeters. Each powermeter has uniqueid(pmid). The schema is like:

```
CREATE TABLE `pmd` (
  `datatime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `pmid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `statusid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `I1` double NOT NULL,
  `I2` double NOT NULL,
  `I3` double NOT NULL,
  `I0` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`datatime`,`pmid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My use case is retrieving hourly(where minute=0),daily(where hour&minute=0),and Monthly record(where day =1 & hour&minute=0) of a specific powermeter.

In the first 2 months, the query works and fast. However, the more records there are, the query time become very slow.

I would like to ask for opinion, how to improve the performance?
There are some thought in my mind:
1.change datetime to seperate field like:

```
`year_2digit` tinyint NOT NULL,
`month` tinyint NOT NULL,
`day` tinyint NOT NULL,
`hour` tinyint NOT NULL,
`minute` tinyint NOT NULL,
```

2.create new table for each month.
Update: Today I read more on web and there is a technique called partitioning. I am interested in it because it doesn't change the schema . I would like to partition by year and month. May I have your opinion as well about partitioning?

Comment: The problem would appear to be a lack of indexes

Comment: What is your MySQL version? And what exactly is your query?

Comment: My MySQL version is 5.7.18. I usually use this to found a hourly record : select * from pmd where pmid = 2 and datatime in ('2017-04-01 00:00','2017-04-01 00:01',...,'2017-04-01 23:59') limit 1440;

Comment: With 5.7.18 you can use [Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first idea is what I would probably also do with some minor exceptions:

Instead of

```
`year_2digit` tinyint
```

I would use

```
`year` year
```

YEAR data type has the same storage size as TINYINT (1 Byte).

Keep the `datatime` column. You might need it for other queries. For example an efficient range condition (like BETWEEN) is a nightmare in MySQL with multiple columns.

The newest MySQL and MariaDB versions support generated (virtual) columns. You can use that feature to automaticly generate the values from the `datetime` columns. If your version doesn't support it, I would use triggers instead.

Define a composite index on `(minute, hour, day, month, year)`. it will support all of the following conditions:

```
WHERE `minute` = 0
WHERE `minute` = 0 AND `hour` = 0
WHERE `minute` = 0 AND `hour` = 0 and `day` = 1
WHERE `minute` = 0 AND `hour` = 0 and `day` = 1 AND `month` = 1
WHERE `minute` = 0 AND `hour` = 0 and `day` = 1 AND `month` = 1
  AND `year` BETWEEN `2010` AND `2020`
```

Comment: Note that your composite index should be in the reverse order to what you mention,  make it `(year, month, day, hour, minute)` , that allows you to do more coarse queries, e.g. a where clause on year, month, day, hour, while still begin able to use this composite index.

Comment: @nos The index that you suggested might be usefull as well, but it's useless for any condition without a fixed year.

Answer (score 0):

> My use case is retrieving hourly(where minute=0),daily(where hour&minute=0),and Monthly record(where day =1 & hour&minute=0) **of a specific powermeter**.

**Part 1 -- Get the right PK**

Since you are looking for one `pmid`, have `PRIMARY KEY(pmid, datetime)`, in *that* order.  And use InnoDB so that the PK is "clustered" with the data.

That way, the rows you need are not scattered all over the table, but are clustered together.  At least for by-minute.

You query must be of this form:

```
WHERE pmid = <constant>
  AND `datetime` >= '2016-07-11'
  AND `datetime`  < '2016-07-11' + INTERVAL 3 DAY
  AND MINUTE(`datetime`) = 0
```

That is, specify the specific pmid and provide a datetime range -- this will focus the scan on a limited part of the table.  Then have the minutely/hourly/etc filtering.

**Part 2 -- Summary Table(s)**

The technique above works quite well for "by minute" over a short time range.  It works terribly over "by day" over a long time range.  This cannot be fixed via an index.

Well, the term "summary table" does not quite fit here, but anyway...  Make two more tables, one for top-of-hour and one for midnight.  Redundantly store those readings in these smaller tables.  The tables have identical schema, just much less data.  The queries will be much faster because, again, they won't be hopping around the data.

A variant on this is to use a `TRIGGER` to copy top-of-hour and midnight values to the other tables.  (Instead of using app code.)

**Partitioning?**

This is a half-baked idea, so I am not sure it will be feasible and efficient.

Use `PARTITION BY LIST` and have 3 partitions:  'minute', 'hour', and 'day'.  There is an extra column with those three values (encoded in some way to keep partitioning happy - so perhaps a tinyint).  Let's say you have

```
scale TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL -- 1=minute, 2=hour, 3=day
```

Add this to the `WHERE`:

```
AND scale >= 2   -- to get hourly data
```

When inserting new data:

```
INSERT INTO pmd
    (scale, pmd, `datetime`, ...)
    VALUES
    (...<see below>, $pmd, $datetime, ...)
```

where the `scale` value is computed by picking apart (in client code or a Stored Function) the `datetime`.

This avoids redundant data implied by Part 2, while providing 3 tables (in the form of 3 partitions).  The "clustering" is excellent.

This needed:

```
PRIMARY KEY(pmd, `datetime`, scale)
```

I said "half baked", but as I typed all this out, it seems to hold together.

If you succeed with the Partitioning, then you win the prize for "Case 5" in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint -- I have been looking for "case 5" for several years.